Pointer moving by itself when a certain mouse is plugged in
Very curious issue. I recently purchased a new mouse, and when i plug the mouse in the cursor begins moving toward the top right of the screen at a constant speed (~ 5 pixels per second, this is affected by my mouse speed in windows settings).
My old mouse works fine, and I have tried updating my drivers / restarting the computer, and the issue does not go away. The new mouse sensor also does not appear to be working, since I cannot actually control the pointer using this new mouse. The right and left mouse buttons work, and i am unable to test middle click / scroll functionality as the mouse is perpetually moving.
Any ideas what could be causing this issue? the new mouse is the Roccat Kone Pro, my OS is Windows 11. Searching online has not yielded any results. Is this a mouse manufacturing defect or could there be another reason?

It's broken - return.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Returned the mouse and got another of the same model. It was in fact a manufacturing defect.

Have you installed the new mouses' drivers correctly?
If so, I'd suggest to test it on a different device in order to find out if these issues also occur there.
If they do, in that case it's probably a defect with the new mouse and you might want to contact support and get it replaced.
